# A shared hook in functional component?

Tags: reactjs

Here is an `example.js` of `hook` in `React` document:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Example() {
  // Declare a new state variable, which we'll call "count"
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here the hook is defined within the functional component `example`. Since there may be multiple functions within a functional component, can I define hook in the component and share the state for all functions in the component? It may look like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);  //<<==here define state `count` 

function doSomethingWithCount() {
  //do something with `count` //<<==here do something with `count`
}

export default function Example() {
  // Declare a new state variable, which we'll call "count"

  doSomethingWithCount();  //<<==here execute the function above

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yes, all `const` variables defined ***within*** a function are in function scope. You should have a review of javascript [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). Your edit won't work (and doesn't match your question), react hooks can only be called at the top level. [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)

Comment: Hooks can only be used unconditionally in a function component, you can create [custom hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html). For example `const useCount = () => useState(1)` But then each function component calling useCount still gets its own count and setCount so count isn't shared. To share you can either use context api with useContext or redux with useSelector.

Comment: Yes, `useContext` or Redux is the best way to do it but I would avoid what you're trying to do because changing state from a different component is a bit confusing. But I'm not sure what's your use-case. You can find a demo for context usage [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-hopper-g4l5h).

Comment: useContext seems a good fit. I am converting class component to functional component.